# How to capture date and time when the button is clicked?

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I am trying to create a web page for my internal team where the agents will select their name and punch their logins and their breaks in time and out time and I want to get this data in the google sheet. I have created the web page however, I am unable to find the code for capturing the date and time when clicking the button.

I have tried running couple of codes but in vain. Below is the html script of webpage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Time Management</h1>
<p>Please select your name: </p>

<form action="/action_page.php">
    <select name="Agent Names">
        <option value="Anita">Anita</option>
        <option value="Jacob">Jacob</option>
        <option value="Agartha">Agartha</option>
        <option value="Smith">Smith</option>
    </select>
      <br><br>
    <button name="Login" type="submit" value="Login">Login</button>

    <p>Please punch your breakfast</p>
        <button name="BreakfastStart" type="submit" value="time" display="time">Start</button>

        <button name="BreakfastEnd" type="submit" value="time">End</button>

    <p>Please punch your lunch</p>
        <button name="LunchStart" type="submit" value="time">Start</button>
        <button name="LunchEnd" type="submit" value="time">End</button>

    <p>Please punch your Snack</p>
        <button name="SnackStart" type="submit" value="time">Start</button>
        <button name="SnackEnd" type="submit" value="time">End</button>

    <p>Please punch your Bio Break</p>
        <button name="BiobreakStart" type="submit" value="time">Start</button>
        <button name="BiobreakStart" type="submit" value="time">End</button>

    <p>Please Logout</p>
    <button name="Logout" type="submit" value="Login">Logout</button>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you have to use something like Javascript

Comment: Are you using your own server or App Script?

Comment: I am using App Script @Andres

Answer (score 0):

This is just the front end html, there’s still a lot of script to write in order to post to a Google Sheet. A simple option is to post directly to a zapier webhook configured to catch and insert into Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a simple function to the buttons and than make your calculations:

```
<button name="BreakfastStart" type="submit" value="time" display="time" onclick="getCurrentTime()">Start</button>

<script>
function getCurrentTime() {
alert(new Date());
}
</script>
```

This is to give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy Apps Script as a Web App [1]. You'll need to create a html file [2] in which you'll put the form you want. Here [3] is well explained how to execute Apps Script functions with JavaScript in the html. Finally, in an Apps Script function you can use the SpreadsheetApp class to insert the values you want [4].

Below it's a working code of what you want, you need to change the "value" attribute of each button to be different so you can use it to check where you want to store that value in the spreadsheet:

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <base target="_top">
      <script>
         function preventFormSubmit() {
           // Set the value of the submitButton input and run processForm function with Form object as parameter 
           var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
           for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {

             buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
             var submitButton = this.value;
             document.getElementById("submitButton").value = submitButton;
             google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateUrl).processForm(document.getElementById("myForm"));
           }) 
           }

           // Prevent forms from submitting.
           var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
           for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
             forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
               event.preventDefault();
             });
           }    
         }

         window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

         function updateUrl(url) {
           var div = document.getElementById('output');
           div.innerHTML = '<a href="#">' + url + '</a>';
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form id="myForm">
         <select name="Agent Names">
            <option value="Anita">Anita</option>
            <option value="Jacob">Jacob</option>
            <option value="Agartha">Agartha</option>
            <option value="Smith">Smith</option>
         </select>
         <br><br>
         <input type="hidden" name="submitButton" id="submitButton">
         <button name="Login"  value="Login">Login</button>
         <p>Please punch your breakfast</p>
         <button name="BreakfastStart"  value="time" display="time">Start</button>
         <button name="BreakfastEnd"  value="time">End</button>
         <p>Please punch your lunch</p>
         <button name="LunchStart"  value="time">Start</button>
         <button name="LunchEnd"  value="time">End</button>
         <p>Please punch your Snack</p>
         <button name="SnackStart"  value="time">Start</button>
         <button name="SnackEnd"  value="time">End</button>
         <p>Please punch your Bio Break</p>
         <button name="BiobreakStart"  value="time">Start</button>
         <button name="BiobreakStart"  value="time">End</button>
         <p>Please Logout</p>
         <button name="Logout"  value="Login">Logout</button>
      </form>
      <div id="output"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**code.gs**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function processForm(form) {
   Logger.log(form);
   Logger.log(form.submitButton)
   var date = new Date();

   //Do operations with the SpreadsheetApp class depending on the form.submitButton value

   return form.submitButton + " was clicked on " + date;
}
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication

[4] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app